# How to randomly select a key from a dictionary based on it's float value

Tags: python, random, probability

Let's say i have a dict

```
{'option one': 5.0, 'option two': 5.0, 'option three': 10.0}
```

How can i randomly select a key based on the probabilities above (ie. option one and two will have a 25% of being chosen. Option 3 would have a 50% chance of being chosen)

Comment: You can use `numpy.random.choice` - it has `p` (probabilities) argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one liner:

```
import random

random.seed(100)
d = {'option one': 5.0, 'option two': 5.0, 'option three': 10.0}
picked = random.choices(*zip(*d.items()))[0]
print(picked)
# option one
```

More broken down:

```
import random

random.seed(100)
d = {'option one': 5.0, 'option two': 5.0, 'option three': 10.0}
# Key-value pairs in dictionary
items = d.items()
# "Transpose" items: from key-value pairs to sequence of keys and sequence of values
values, weights = zip(*items)
# Weighted choice (of one element)
picked = random.choices(values, weights)[0]
print(picked)
# option one
```

Note [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) (which, unlike [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), offers a `weights` parameter) was added on Python 3.6.